# how to disable outside scrolling while mat-autocomplete panel is open?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Opening a mat-autocomplete in Angular Material doesn't prevent background content from scrolling. I have tried using  block strategy and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *Try this strategy*--[Hide scroll when input field focused]

Add focus and focusout on your input field and implement methods for that.

### in HTML--

```
(focus)="focusinmethod()"
(focusout)="focusoutmethod()"
```

### in typescript--

```
  focusinmethod(){
    let b = document.body;
    b.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
  focusoutmethod(){
    let b = document.body;
    b.style.overflow = "auto";
  }
```

here I'm providing stackbliz example too. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hide-scroll?file=src/app/autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html)